# How to use keystrokes to browse with Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, shortcuts

Very often, when I use a file manager, I like to use the keyboard to move around.
In Nautilus this is very difficult.

For example, when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> with a folder selected, it opens; but how can I close it gain? In some other file managers you can do so by pressing  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Return opens a folder, then the shortcut for 'Back' is Alt-LeftArrow

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [list of Nautilus keyboard shortcuts](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/8480/one-liner-gnome-nautilus-keyboard-shortcuts/), this might help you.

Open a folder with <kbd>↵</kbd>, go back with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/06/27/gnome-and-nautilus-keyboard-shortcut-keys/) pretty much has every keyboard shortcut you need in Nautilus. For future reference, searching for `<application> keyboard shortcuts` will yield many results with the type of information you are looking for.